# How can I separate emails like in gmail, outlook, or on the iphone on commas?

Tags: javascript, email, user-experience, email-validation

I am having my users type in multiple email addresses in one portion of my app. Every time they press comma or semicolon, I want that email to split off into an individual cell, kind of like tags in stack overflow:

[image]

I was wondering if their were any plugins or simple ways of acheiving this.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found an option right after posting the question and searching for a while:

http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/